# Shell Commands not working : REDHAT

Tags: bash, shell, redhat-enterprise-linux

I added some service to the startup script and then after reboot , i got this message-

```
24 package(s) needed for security, out of 52 available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: tty: command not found
-bash: mktemp: command not found
-bash: $TMP: ambiguous redirect
-bash: rm: command not found
```

and then when i try to run most of the basic commands like `netstat`,  `ps`, `grep`, `ll` etc , i get a error message like this

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

but some commands like `cp` , `chkconfig` are working. I have checked that my /bin/bash file is present. what can be the reason ?

but before that i made following changes

```
echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45" >> /etc/profile.d/custpath.sh
echo "export JAVA_HOME" >> /etc/profile.d/custpath.sh
echo 'PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> /etc/profile.d/custpath.sh
echo "export PATH" >> /etc/profile.d/custpath.sh
```

and 
changed /etc/environment file to

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you have clobbered your path.  What happens if you prefix the commands which don't work with their full path, and what does 'echo $PATH' show ?

Comment: Either your `$PATH` is messed up, or somebody just hacked into your system and tried to cover their tracks -- I've been in that situation. Can you post the output of `/bin/echo $PATH`? What happens if you run `/bin/ls`?